# SSH user public key info

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, public-key

I want to find out which SSH user started my script on a server via SSH, i.e. which public key was used for the user to log in.

`SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable gives me the client's IP address.

I would also like to know which public key from `authorized_keys` was used and its comment (usually email).

I am looking for a solution without fiddling with `sshd` and its logs, so that I would not need to set up the target servers. The only thing known for sure is that the script is run on Ubuntu servers. Also my user doesn't have `sudo` rights.

Comment: As the user can't sudo, are they logging in as their OWN user? if so, then why not just look at the user whom started the process? If not, you need to look at the time the shell the user is logged into started, and align that with a login entry in the sshd log.

Comment: "I want to find out which SSH user started my script on a server via SSH, i.e. which public key was used for the user to log in." Are you saying that multiple people share a single SSH user account?

Comment: > Are you saying that multiple people share a single SSH user account?
Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information isn't available to you by default. But it can be achieved in a couple of different ways.

**As unprivileged user**

You can make use of some of the features available in the `authorized_keys` file format. The feature I think is most useful to you is `environment`.

At the beginning of each line of `authorized_keys` in front of the key itself you put a string like this:

```
environment="SSH_KEY=name"
```

Where you substitute a different value for `name` on each line. This will set an environment variable called `SSH_KEY` when that particular line of `authorized_keys` is used for authentication. The full set of features you can make use of can be found using `man sshd`.

**As system administrator**

Enable the `ExposeAuthInfo` setting in `sshd_config` and reload the daemon. Then `sshd` will write the information you are looking for to a temporary file. The path to this file can be found in the `SSH_USER_AUTH` environment variable.

More information about such settings can be found using `man sshd_config`.

Answer (score 1):

/var/log/auth.log will contain en entry like:

```
Accepted publickey for <userid> from <IP address> port 57762 ssh2: RSA SHA256: <43 random characters>
```

The "random characters" are the fingerprint of the public key used. You can tell the fingerprints of the keys in your local authorized_keys file using:

```
ssh-keygen -lf /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

which lists the fingerprint of each key together with the key's comment (which is usually an email..)

Comment: Unfortunately, non-admin users don't have access to that file.

Comment: This answer is just what I needed. I am surprised that I found it on [su] and not [sf].

Comment: @warvariuc You are right, this does not answer your question. It is still a very useful answer, just not for your particular question. What you are looking for is an environment variable containing the same string that was written to the log. I don't know if such an environment variable exists.

Comment: @warvariuc I checked a couple of Ubuntu 18.04 systems. And no such environment variable exists by default. There is however a `ExposeAuthInfo` setting which is disabled by default, but could be enabled to achieve this. However I just recalled that there is another way to achieve this which doesn't require changes to `sshd_config`. I have written an answer detailing both solutions.